# How to change friction coefficient and moment of inertia in CompassGait？

Tags: drake

There is no api description about change friction coefficient and moment of inertia in CompassGait in https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.examples.compass_gait.html. What's the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a missing API -- those concepts are explicitly missing from the mathematical model.  The assumption of infinite friction (no slip) allows us to capture the dynamics in minimal coordinates with a single mode.  The point mass assumptions could be replaced with inertias without much additional complexity, but that's not how we have derived these equations.

The "searching for limit cycles" exercise in my course notes derives the equations with friction explicitly: (currently the first exercise in this chapter http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/simple_legs.html)

Comment: Also,I found when I set mass_hip=0, there would be "ValueError: Points cannot contain NaN". Can the mathematical model be simplified further?